# How to control the number of buffered frames of VLCkit?

Tags: ios, video-streaming

I have just built VLC library for iOS at [VLCKit](https://github.com/strukturag/VLCKit)
and using it to display a video stream. I need to make it displays in real-time with a lowest latency, so I tried to find a way to reduce the number of buffered frames (or something similar to it) before display on an UIView. 
I started looking in the module MobileVLCKit but it seems no property allows me to control that.

I am wondering if the change can be accomplished on MobileVLCKit itself or on the VLC library.
If so, will I need to modify the library and rebuild it? What is the parameter should I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a mount of time to look into the vlc library without successful, I tried to stream with rtsp instead of rtmp protocol and the real-time of video produced has been improved.

Thus i also found a workaround solution by setting a timer to force player moves forward the buffered frames. It might cause jagging but keep video in more real-time.